How to Optimize MySQL for our Site
A search for activities of a certain type (ID 95) on a large site takes a long time. The civicrm_activity table has 3,836,452 rows. The machine is a VPN with 6 CPU cores and 8GB memory.
It appears the bottleneck is this query:
SELECT 
    civicrm_activity.id,
    contact_a.id AS contact_id,
    contact_a.contact_type AS contact_type,
    contact_a.contact_sub_type AS contact_sub_type,
    contact_a.sort_name AS sort_name,
    contact_a.display_name AS display_name,
    civicrm_activity.id AS activity_id,
    civicrm_activity.activity_type_id,
    civicrm_activity.subject AS activity_subject,
    civicrm_activity.activity_date_time AS activity_date_time,
    civicrm_activity.status_id AS activity_status_id,
    civicrm_activity.source_record_id AS source_record_id,
    civicrm_activity.is_test AS activity_is_test,
    civicrm_activity.campaign_id AS activity_campaign_id,
    civicrm_activity.engagement_level AS activity_engagement_level,
    source_contact.sort_name AS source_contact,
    civicrm_activity.status_id AS status_id,
    civicrm_activity.engagement_level AS engagement_level
FROM 
    civicrm_contact contact_a
LEFT JOIN 
    civicrm_activity_contact ON civicrm_activity_contact.contact_id = contact_a.id
LEFT JOIN 
    civicrm_activity ON civicrm_activity.id = civicrm_activity_contact.activity_id
    AND civicrm_activity.is_deleted = 0 
    AND civicrm_activity.is_current_revision = 1
INNER JOIN 
    civicrm_contact ON civicrm_activity_contact.contact_id = civicrm_contact.id 
    AND civicrm_contact.is_deleted != 1
LEFT JOIN 
    civicrm_activity_contact source_activity ON source_activity.activity_id = civicrm_activity_contact.activity_id
    AND source_activity.record_type_id = 2
LEFT JOIN 
    civicrm_contact source_contact ON source_activity.contact_id = source_contact.id
WHERE  
    civicrm_activity.activity_type_id IN (95) 
    AND civicrm_activity.is_test = 0 
    AND contact_a.is_deleted = 0 
    AND civicrm_activity.activity_type_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 57, 59, 61, 63, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104)
GROUP BY 
    civicrm_activity.id
ORDER BY 
    activity_date_time DESC, 
    contact_a.id
LIMIT 0, 50;

which takes 65 seconds.
The last AND clause of the WHERE clause is superfluous, but anyhow, we will try to add more memory and see if increasing Innodb_buffer_pool_size will help.
Beyond that, does anyone have any suggestions how to improve the speed here?

Try this:
SELECT 
    civicrm_activity.id,
    contact_a.id AS contact_id,
    contact_a.contact_type AS contact_type,
    contact_a.contact_sub_type AS contact_sub_type,
    contact_a.sort_name AS sort_name,
    contact_a.display_name AS display_name,
    civicrm_activity.activity_type_id,
    civicrm_activity.subject AS activity_subject,
    civicrm_activity.activity_date_time AS activity_date_time,
    civicrm_activity.status_id AS activity_status_id,
    civicrm_activity.source_record_id AS source_record_id,
    civicrm_activity.is_test AS activity_is_test,
    civicrm_activity.campaign_id AS activity_campaign_id,
    civicrm_activity.engagement_level AS activity_engagement_level,
    source_contact.sort_name AS source_contact
FROM 
    civicrm_contact contact_a
LEFT JOIN 
    civicrm_activity_contact ON civicrm_activity_contact.contact_id = contact_a.id
LEFT JOIN 
    civicrm_activity ON civicrm_activity.id = civicrm_activity_contact.activity_id
    AND civicrm_activity.is_deleted = 0 
    AND civicrm_activity.is_current_revision = 1
LEFT JOIN 
    civicrm_activity_contact source_activity ON source_activity.activity_id = civicrm_activity_contact.activity_id
    AND source_activity.record_type_id = 2
LEFT JOIN 
    civicrm_contact source_contact ON source_activity.contact_id = source_contact.id
WHERE  
    civicrm_activity.activity_type_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 57, 59, 61, 63, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104)
    AND civicrm_activity.is_test = 0 
    AND contact_a.is_deleted = 0 
GROUP BY 
    civicrm_activity.id
ORDER BY 
    activity_date_time DESC, 
    contact_a.id
LIMIT 50;


Removed Redundant Fields: activity_type_id, status_id, and engagement_level are selected twice in the query, so we can eliminate the duplicates.
Optimized Filters in WHERE Clause: In WHERE, activity_type_id IN (95) and the long activity_type_id list can be simplified to remove 95 if already covered by the larger list.
Removed Redundant INNER JOIN Condition: The line INNER JOIN civicrm_contact ON civicrm_activity_contact.contact_id = civicrm_contact.id appears redundant if contact_a already represents this data.
Duplicate Data: Since GROUP BY is used on civicrm_activity.id, it may be worth only including fields from civicrm_activity that are truly needed.

Finally, indexing the columns used in the WHERE, JOIN and ORDER BY clauses should speed things up as well.

These are useful comments but the query is likely coming from civi as the result of some search function and can't be changed, so I think the poster is asking for what kinds of things they can do either in the UI or at the hosting level. Note also the index issue is a known problem because actually adding indexes on e.g. is_deleted/is_current_revision is somewhat useless, because the majority of records have is_deleted=0 and is_current_revision=1, so it can't use the index and does a full table scan. If can find in the code where to implement your suggestions that would of course be good too.
